# Hadoop Installation and Running Taking Too Long in Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, hadoop

I successfully installed hadoop version 3.2.2 and have Java version 8 (JDK 1.8.0) and followed the tutorial here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7Qpnmi0Q-s

Here are my executions when running Hadoop in command prompt here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The issue here is that hadoop (version 3.2.2) is taking way too long to load after successfully installing it in my local drive exactly like in the tutorial I followed above. I don't receive any errors or shutdown terminals after running start-dfs.cmd and start-yarn.cmd.

I can send how I set up my environment variables but I believe that I followed exactly that as described in the tutorial. Here is my setup:

[image]

Is there a solution to solve this issue?

I tried other StackOverflow posts but none of them specified how to tackle my issue with not loading Hadoop quickly. It actually never finishes loading even without errors or shutdowns.

Comment: You should enable DEBUG logging which will give you more information.

Comment: "Taking too long" isn't really a question. Yes, of course starting at least 4 Java processes will take time and slow down your machine. Starting a Hadoop cluster is never quick. What specifically do you need it for, though? Spark or Hive can run fine locally without it, for example.

Comment: I am just learning Hadoop for the first time as a beginner for Big Data. Spark works but Hadoop is slow. I am trying to access local host for Hadoop